# 'Require' in Angular Directives with '^^'

Tags: javascript, angularjs

There is the following code:

```
ff.directive('radarMapMap', {
  restrict: 'A',
  require: '^^radarMap',
  link: function (scope, element, attrs, mapCtrl) {
    mapCtrl.setMapElement(element);
  }
});
```

I don't understand what is the difference between `require: '^radarMap'` and `require: '^^radarMap'`. I didn't find it in documentation. Please, make me clear. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

from the documentation:

^ - Locate the required controller by searching the element and its parents. Throw an error if not found.

^^ - Locate the required controller by searching the element's parents. Throw an error if not found.

Read it here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile

Comment: added it, check it out :)

Answer (score 0):

Directive definition options are described [in the docs](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0/docs/api/ng/service/$compile#-require-):

> `^` - Locate the required controller by searching the element and its parents. Throw an error if not found.
>
> `^^` - Locate the required controller by searching the element's parents. Throw an error if not found.